# why I am unable to print length value in this question?

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct rect
{
   int length;
   int breadth;
};

void initialize(struct rect *r,int l , int b)
{
    r->length=l;
    r->breadth=b;
}

void changelength(struct rect *r,int l)
{
    r->length=l;
}

int area(struct rect r)
{
    return(r.length*r.breadth);
}

int main()
{
    struct rect r;
    initialize(&r,10,5);
    changelength(&r,3);
    area(r);
    printf("The rectangle is %d and %d\n",initialize);
    printf("The length is %d\n",changelength);
    printf("The area is %d",area(r));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to spend some more time with a beginners book, and read it from the very beginning. Except for the last printout, that's not how you print "results" from functions.

Comment: Neither `initialize` or `changelength` returns any value, so there is no value to print from those two functions.

Comment: that's what i want how to print that stuff from function . I want to return a value then what to do??

Comment: Use flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and everything will be clear: https://godbolt.org/z/9GEvGeK69

Comment: @cptFracassa Neither `initialize` or `changelength` are _invoked_ in the `printf()` instructions, they are just used as identifiers. So there wouldn't be any return value to print here even if the functions were returning some. A function identifier by itself represents a pointer to the function. Those pointers' size may by coincidence fit the size of `int`, which might result in printing _some_ values. But that is not guaranteed and not even supposed to work in any meaningfulr, or even predictable way.

Comment: @CiaPan You're right of course, I overlooked that.

Comment: This code doesn't look like [C++], please consider retagging to [C].

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is something like this:

```
struct rect r;

initialize(&r, 10, 5);
printf("The rectangle is %d and %d\n", r.length, r.breadth);

changelength(&r, 3);
printf("The length is %d\n", r.length);

printf("The area is %d\n", area(r));
```

Comment: thanks but i knew it . I was looking for to return a value from functions made like i returned for area. likewise by writing any returning statement in function as i had written in for calculating area.. Is there any way to do so??

Comment: @Rishav just change the two functions in question to return what you want, but then you need to actually call them from the print-statements to. Note however that your code looks like old C-code, and looks bad from a C++ perspective.

Comment: @Rishav One problem is that you can't return two values from the `initialize` function. It also makes no sense to return values from these functions. It only makes sense to return the calculated area from the `area` function.